# Check Image in Byte[] Empty or not?

Tags: android

I am getting image from DB.

```
byte[] outImage = student.getImage();//This Method returns Image
imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
mImg.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Now I want to check **outImage** is empty or not?

Answer (score 1):

If it is empty then you should check if null or not.

If it is not empty then you also check if it has content or not -

***So try with the condition -***

```
if (outImage == null || outImage.length == 0)
  return;
else
{
    imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    mImg.setImageBitmap(theImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Condition:-

if (outImage.length==0) {



        }else{

   imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        mImg.setImageBitmap(theImage);
}
```